# What Happens if Fulfill is called Twice on a Promise

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-remote-config, promisekit

This code is blocking the UI until the remote config fetch is done. I have put 2 seconds as timeout. Here both **completionHandler** and **after** will execute, whichever finishes first.

Will it be ok? Or do I need to take care that only one should execute?

```
func checkIfRemoteConfigFetched<T>(t:T) -> Promise<T>{
        return Promise<T>{ seal in

            if self.rConfig?.fetchComplete == true{
                seal.fulfill(t)
            }

            after(seconds: 2).done{
                seal.fulfill(t)
            }

            if let rConfig = self.rConfig{
                rConfig.completionHandler = { success in
                        seal.fulfill(t)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are not fetching anything here. Using `promise` is irrelevant.

Comment: @Kamran I am fetching remote config, which is an async network call.

Comment: In promise 6, you can call fulfill multiple times. It's not problem. `done` block called 1 time.